# How to know my media file playing has been stopped in android

Tags: android, media-player

I have a buttons called play and stop
if I press play its starting playing. after I press stop its going to home page. But I need to go home page automatically once playing is done ie. Without clicking stop button. How can I do it for android?
thanks in advance

Comment: you have to compare media player getDuration with media player current duration .. both are same when your song is over..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hi shekhar you can set an oncomplete listener to the player object. The code follows:

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){@Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  "your code comes here" }});
```

here the mPlayer is the object of the MediaPlayer which is currently running..